# Is there any way to use VC++ 2010 without including stdafx.h?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-2010

I've successfully installed M$ VC2010 and start writing simple programs using it.

I am very annoyed from the `#include<stdafx.h>`, So is there any way to compile and run programs without it???

Comment: Is it really still cool to spell it with a dollar sign?

Comment: Precompiled headers can speed up build times a lot - you might find it even more annoying waiting three times as long for your build to complete...

Comment: About M$, ya, I don't like it, so I call it M$

Comment: It's amazing to read "M$" right on the day Apple surpasses Microsoft market cap.

Comment: So, we can find a new name of apple too :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's for pre-compiled headers. Don't use pre-compiled headers, don't include it.

Answer (score 6):

Goto `Project Settings->Precompiled Headers.`
Select `Not using precompiled headers.`

Answer (score 6):

You can also turn off precompiled headers per file.

Setting this in VS Express C++ 2012 is as follows:

1. In Project Explorer right-click on .cpp file, select Properties.
2. On the left pane select Configuration Properties/C++/ Precompiled
   Headers
3. Now, on the right pane there is 'Precompiled Header' value which
   you can change from **Use /Yu** to :

   - 'Not Using Precompiled Headers'

Cheers
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Of course, just go to Project Settings, C/C++ → Precompiled Headers, and choose "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

BTW: On large projects using precompiled headers may significantly decrease build time.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your project, create an empty project.

For now, you can disable it in Project Settings.